# Trouble installing Ubuntu 16.04 along side with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, 16.04, partitioning, system-installation, windows-10

I'm trying to install `Ubuntu 16.04` along side with `Windows 10`. But on installation I am not getting the below option

> Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10

[image]
Here is my partition

[image]

As you can see 80gb unallocated space, that's where I'm trying to install ubuntu.

I read some article and they said that it has to do something with dynamic partition. Dynamic partition has to be converted to basic partition then only It will visible to ubuntu. I do not know what exactly the problem is, can anybody help.

Comment: Anyone who attempts dual booting without reading https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-on_self-test , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table , https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UEFI is doomed to confusion, failure and frustration.

Comment: Hi Atinesh, I would guess that you didn't get the "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10" option because you have more than one chunk of unallocated space (but I'm not positive).  If you select "Something else", you should get the opportunity to use the 81 GB chunk to 1) create a swap partition, and 2) install Ubuntu.  As a rule of thumb, the swap partition should be about twice the size of your RAM (but bigger than 16 GB is probably a waste).  Regarding your article, I haven't seen it, and I don't know what it's about, but if you edit your question to include a link to it I'll read it :)

Comment: @rclocher3 When I clicked "Somethng else" option I got this window https://s28.postimg.org/h9041szh9/IMG_20161210_213508281_HDR.jpg
But '+' button is disabled and also I can not be able to see 80gb unallocated space here

Comment: In the "Something else" window, it looks as though you have four primary partitions, and no extended partition.  There can be only four "primary" partitions, so if you want more partitions then you have to make one of the first four an extended partition, that can contain more partitions.  All that is probably in waltinator's link about Master Boot Record.

Comment: Windows 10 uses UEFI and GPT.  There **isn't any** MBR.  You can use diskmgmt.msc to create space for Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most partitioning options are hidden behind the "Something else" option. Just select that and hit next. That will bring you to a window where you can setup your Ubuntu partitions, alongside with a visual layout with existing partitions. Nothing will be done to your disk until after that view.

Comment: When I clicked "Somethng else" option I got this window https://s28.postimg.org/h9041szh9/IMG_20161210_213508281_HDR.jpg

But '+' button is disabled and also I can not be able to see 80gb unallocated space here.

Comment: The diskmgmt.msc utility can be used to create space for Linux.

Comment: @Thufir I've created the space using diskmgmt.msc but it's not visible during installation.

Comment: @Atinesh ask a new question.  you want to install to **free** space, not a partition.